# Ionic 3: Back Button Hardware Event Handler Can't Determine Overlay Views

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app

I have an ionic 3 application and I modified the functionality of the hardware back button. It works on pages but it cannot determine whether overlay views like modals and alert dialog boxes are present or not.

**Here is my code**

```
    this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => { 
      let nav = app._appRoot._getActivePortal() || app.getActiveNav();
      let activeView = nav.getActive().instance;

      if (activeView != null) {
        if (nav.canGoBack()) {
            if (activeView instanceof MultiRegistrationOne || activeView instanceof MultiRegistrationTwo || activeView instanceof MultiRegistrationThree) {
                // do something
            } else {
               nav.pop();
            }
        } else if (activeView.isOverlay) {
          activeView.dismiss();
        } else {
          let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Ionic App',
            message: 'Do you want to close the app?',
            buttons: [{
              text: 'Cancel',
              role: 'cancel',
              handler: () => {
                console.log('Application exit prevented!');
              }
            },
            {
              text: 'Close',
              handler: () => {
                this.platform.exitApp();
              }
            }]
          });
          alert.present();
        }
      }
    });
```

I hope someone can help me with this. Thank you in advance

Comment: I solved it using MD. Riyas' answer here: [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51331990/10622230)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using MD. Riyas' answer here: [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51331990/10622230)

Answer (score 0):

declare a variable :`viewController:ViewController`
then in your page or app.components.ts , modify your back button handle to be like the

```
this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
  try{
    this.viewController.dismiss()

  }
  catch(e){
    console.log("error");
  }

});
```

Comment: Hello. I have tried your solution but it returns an error "MyApp_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError[ViewController]: 
  StaticInjectorError[ViewController]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ViewController!" I don't know why, and my app gets stuck on the splash screen.

Comment: the error tells you that there is no viewController to be dismissed , you want to add this dismiss handler in one page or in the hole app ? and about the stuck in splash screen , that's because of that error , please try to but the back button in one page not in app.component and tell me

Comment: I want to implement this on the whole application since I have different behavior for each back button event. So in order for me to save a bunch of codes by repeating this on each and every page, I added it on the app.component.ts

Comment: the code working fine on my application and it's on app.components , just check to use try catch and import the packages as well

Comment: I have tried your code. Still returns the same error. I put your code on app.component.ts and I also declared the variable.